# how to edit local.ini to enable CROS with couchdb

Tags: angular, http, couchdb

I have simple app using couchdb with angular..
I need to fetch the data stored in couchdb using angular http injection.
but I has this error in console :"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin"

After searching I found that I have to edit local.ini file located at this path:
C:\CouchDB\etc
but I had this error :"the permission do not allow you to make modifications"

Question: is there is any way allow me to edit this file (I am using windows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using CouchDB 2.XX ? If yes, you can simply go to Fauxton (`host/_utils`) and in the config tab, click on Enable CORS and set the allowed domains.

Otherwise, if you're using CouchDB 1.6.1, you can go to the configuration tab and add the following category/key value:

---

httpd/enable_cors `true`

cors/origins `*`

cors/credentials `true`

cors/method `GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, DELETE`

cors/headers `accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer, x-csrf-token`

See [this link](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb#what-it-does) for further explanation